# modal auto height & width

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm calling the content for this script via Ajax. Is their anyway to have the height and width auto adjust to the content being called?

```
        <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 600,
                modal:true
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });
    });
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you float your div with css, it should autoadjust to it's content. So try:

```
<div style="float: left;"></div>
```

To break the float, you could call div with css-clear:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```